# System component check on Mac

Tags: mac, components

Recently I left my Mac (in a case) in the car for probably less than an hour, and the temperatures were extremely high (in Arizona) definitely in the 100s. I got back and pulled out my computer to see if it was hot and the unibody was extremely hot but when I got home and turned it on everything works fine.

Wondering if any internal damage was done. If so, how can I do a "check"?

Answer (score 0):

If it was off, or sleeping, you're probably fine. There's no way to check other than using it and seeing if it's acting strange or tearing it apart and visually verifying - but even then you can't know for sure. If it was left on in those temps you run more of a risk, but modern computers, both PC and Mac, will shut themselves down when getting too hot.

I wouldn't worry much.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it was off the whole time. I just was surprised at how hot the metal unibody was, hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Diagnostics tool on the OS X installation or applications DVD that cam with your machine. For more info see [this page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1509).

Quick guide:

1. Insert the correct DVD
2. Shut down your MacBook
3. Press and hold 'D' and start the machine.

that way you can do some basic HW checks. If you hav your MacBook covered by an AppleCare protection plan you are allowed to download a tool called TechTool Pro, which does some basic tests, too.

Answer (score 0):

[This is more of a comment than an answer, but it needed more space/formatting than the comment box allows.]

FYI, here are the temperature specs for the current MacBook Pro. Other Mac models are roughly the same.

- Operating temperature: 50° to 95° F (10° to 35° C)
- Storage temperature: -13° to 113° F (-24° to 45° C)

It's not hard for the temperature inside a car to reach 113° F even on relatively mild days, so the moral of this story is, if you want to keep it within the parameters the system has been designed and tested to support, do not leave your Mac in your car, and if you do, certainly don't use it until it cools down a bit.